# PPTPD with PAM authentication?

Tags: vpn, pam, pptpd

I need a VPN solution for my company. One requirement is to be able to use the built-in windows VPN client. We are running a Debian Etch server.

I've managed to set up PPTPD but the authentication is based on the chap-secrets file. We already have all the user accounts set up on the server, so it'd be nice to use PAM authentication to get user/pass directly from the unix login.

Is this possible to achieve and how? If not, is there any other VPN solution that can do this? Don't tell me OpenVPN, it needs additional software to be installed on the Windows machines. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but I believe [PopTop](http://www.poptop.org/) will do this for *nix environments. Way back in the day you had to throw a RADIUS setup in between PopTop and PAM, but I think it supports it natively now.

And of course Routing and Remote Access does this for Windows Servers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same solution, it seems that ppp has support for this, but it's very poorly documented and I can't find any examples where it's working.

Did you manage to get it working?

EDIT:

Actually I wound this,

http://www.mail-archive.com/freeradius-users@lists.freeradius.org/msg45587.html

Which states that it's not possible, it actually makes sense too, unfortunately.